# Java Generic Class in use

Tags: java, multithreading, generics

A lot of search coudnt help me with my problem. 
While refactoring a lot of code, which realize Producer-Consumer pattern, i get a problem with a simple composition.

By the end of refactoring we have a very simple structure

1) A class Spooler, that shedules Consumer threads.

2) An abstract class AbstractConsumer, that contains some real methods and variables and one abstract method run();

3) Subclasses - real Consumers, that extend AbstractConsumer and override run() method.

```
class Spooler {

        private int spoolSize = 100;
        private Consumer[] spool = null;
        //private ArrayList<? extends Consumer> spool = null;
        //...

        public Spooler() {
            init();
        }

        public final void init() {
            if (spool == null) {
                spool = new ArrayList<Consumer>();
                for (int i = 0; i < spool.size(); i++) {
                    spool.add(new Consumer(null, null));
                    spool[i] = new Consumer();
                    spool[i].start();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractConsumer extends Thread {
        //some NOT ABSTRACT variables and methods

        @Override
        public abstract void run();

    }

    class XmlConsumer extends Consumer {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //consume current task 
        }
    }
```

So, what i want. When i need some multithreading dataprocessing, i realize current Consumer, override run() method of abstract superclass. Realize new Spooler, which constructor have to get the currentConsumer. And then all it have to work, i think.

I don't know how to add AbstractConsumer into Spoolers ArrayList without implementation its abstract methods. Like that

```
for (int i = 0; i < spool.size(); i++) {
            spool.add(new AbstractConsumer() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }
            })

}
```

I think, its need to use Java Generics Classes here, i tried hard, but all fails. Please tell me how can i solve my problem. Thank you =)

Comment: Where do you define Consumer class? Is Consumer a subclass of AbstractConsumer?

Comment: Since Consumer extends AbstractConsumer, you can make your ArrayList of type AbstractConsumer.

Comment: Yes, Consumer is subclass of AbstractConsumer. I can define it in any class, where i want to make multithreading dataprocessing.

ArrayList <AbstractConsumer> which fiils in Spooler fails on the add() method, because adding abstract instance means implement its abstract methods like in an example i've posted.

Comment: Do consumers have a constructor that always receives the same arguments? I see two constructors for `Consumer` in your code: `new Consumer()` and `new Consumer(null, null)`. What about all the other consumers?

Comment: Sorry for errors in javacode, i tried to simplify to illustrate question, but it was inattantive. Sorry =)

Answer (score 1):

if you want your spooler to be generic, you should compose it with a factory that you inject in the constructor of the spooler

```
interface ConsummerFactory {
  public AbstractConsummer create();
}
```

so in the `init` method of your spooler, you invoke the `create` method of the factory

then if you want a spooler of `XmlConsumer` you just need to implement a `ConsummerFactory` whose `create` method create a `XmlConsummer` and give it as argument of the constructor of your spooler

Comment: Thank tou very much. I go another way, i think factory is too difficult solution, maybe i'm wrong. Now its realized with the reflection. Maybe its not the best decision.